# I am getting an error in SSRS when using conditional formatting for filling a textbox. Error BC30201

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am getting the following error for my conditional formatting expression in SSRS.

> The BackgroundColor expression for the text box ‘Textbox84’ contains an error: [BC30201] Expression expected.

The expression I am using is:

```
=IIF(Fields!Sold_For_More_.Value='Yes',#cf1d17,"Transparent")
```

I have tried messing around with the quotations around "Yes", but am getting the same error.

Comment: Its definitely double quotes. Shouldn't `#cf1d17` be quoted also?

Comment: Wow, that was the issue.  Double quotes around both the "Yes" and the hex.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The correct expression should be

```
=IIF(Fields!Sold_For_More_.Value="Yes","#cf1d17","Transparent")
```

Comment: Better replace "Transparent" with Nothing. I always get warning when "Transparent" is used